# How to resize the width and height of SVG social icons?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, styles

I want to resize the social icons on the top header of this website http://petlet.net.au/

[image]

I thought that the logo's are images but I think these logos are from a library or from external because when you inspect the code there's no `<img src>` code.

This is the code:

[image]

How can I resize the social icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, or fa-5x** classes.

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i> //smallest
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i> 
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i> 
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-4x"></i> 
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-5x"></i> //biggest
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever icons are used as `svg` icons you can resize them by just changing `font-size`. They can be colored, not colored, multiple shapes, sizes, whatever.

```
.header .fa {
    font-size: 15px;  // you can increase or decrease font size as per your needs.
}

.header .fa-facebook-square {
    font-size: 18px; // you can change font-sizes of different icons indiviually
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using font-size css property you can resize the font-awesome fonts.

Try this:

```
.top-header-content  a{
   font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer version use icon-2x, icon-3x etc.

```
<i class="icon-camera-retro icon-4x"></i>
```

Refer http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Just use `font-size` property of CSS to resize the social icon buttons